# Swift - Parse Facebook "Invalid redeclaration of 'applicationDidBecomeActive'"

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement the Parse Facebook login functions and I receive a `Invalid redeclaration of 'applicationDidBecomeActive'`. I'm not exactly sure where to pinpoint this error is coming from.

Here is the line that is triggering the error in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
**func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {**
        FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }
```

Here is the full file's code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxxx", clientKey:"xxxxxxx")
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
            return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication,
                withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }
}
```

Here is my bridging header file:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

I can't seem to pinpoint the exact error since the code is coming straight out of the Parse.com documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, you're redeclaring `applicationDidBecomeActive` - it's listed in your source code twice.

Remove the following lines from the file

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```